# Get object from pointer in ctypes

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

My dll has function createBridge that returns pointer to the object of Bridge type. How can I call methods of Bridge class instance?

```
bridge_dll = cdll.LoadLibrary("bridge.dll")
p = c_double(bridge_dll.createBridge())
bridge = POINTER(p)
bridge.initialize()
```

This code result is:

> line 14, in run
>       bridge = POINTER(p) TypeError: must be a ctypes type

Comment: ...`c_double`? Why did you call `c_double` there?

Comment: `ctypes` is for C.  It has no concept for object methods.  You can wrap the C++ interface in a C interface if needed.